# Mixing wide and narrow string literals in C

Tags: c, string-literals, widestring

Just found out that all of the following work:

```
printf( "%ls\n", "123" L"456" );
printf( "%ls\n", L"123" "456" );
printf( "%ls\n", L"123" L"456" );
```

The output is

```
123456
123456
123456
```

Why can I freely mix and match wide and narrow string literals to get a wide string literal as a result? Is that a documented behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is that a documented behavior?

Yes, this behavior is supported by the standard, from section `6.4.5` *String literals* paragrph *4* of the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says (*emphasis mine*):

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of
>   adjacent character and wide string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte
>   character sequence. **If any of the tokens are wide string literal tokens, the resulting
>   multibyte character sequence is treated as a wide string literal**; otherwise, it is treated as a character string literal.

Answer (score 6):

**6.4.5 String literals**

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by
>   any sequence of  adjacent character and wide string literal tokens are
>   concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence. If any of the
>   tokens are wide string literal tokens, the resulting multibyte
>   character sequence is treated as a wide string literal; otherwise, it
>   is treated as a character string literal.